# A KML File generated by Java API KML can't be deleted

Tags: java, kml

I generated a kml file with the api JavaAPIforKML version 2.2 like that :

```
         try {
            File kmlFile =files.get(TypeOfFile.kml);
            kmlMaker.marshal(kmlFile);
            logger.debug("The file " + kmlFile.getPath() + " has been created");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new CoreServiceException("Error while the creation of KML file", e);
        }
```

After the generation, I tried to delete the kml file with this code but it doesn't work :

```
         for(int i=0;i<directoryFiles.length;i++){

            String filePath = directoryFiles[i].getPath();

            boolean fileIsDeleted = false;
            try {
                FileDeleteStrategy.FORCE.delete(directoryFiles[i]);
                fileIsDeleted = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(fileIsDeleted) logger.debug("The file " + filePath + " has been deleted");
            else logger.error("The file " + filePath + " hasn't been deleted");
        }
```

This exception is throwed : java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: C:\DEV\Tmp\KML\3013899924069204776\1662188016.kml

Have you some suggestions for me ? I took a look in the source code of the api but I don't have all sources, I think the outputStream is not closed inside the api.

You'll find below a little JUnit on this problem and you can noticed that the delete of the file doesn't work :

```
@Test
public void deleteKML() throws Exception {
    Kml kmlMaker = new Kml();
    File kmlFile = new File("C:\\Dev\\Tmp\\KML\\TEST1-913289299.kml");
    kmlMaker.marshal(kmlFile);

    Assert.assertTrue(kmlFile.delete());

}
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that this issue hasn't yet resolved : [Issue 21 - JAVA KML API](http://code.google.com/p/javaapiforkml/issues/detail?id=21)